# How to do ADD/SUB signed or unsigned integer correctly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I saw there is an `ADD` instruction on ARM, does it work for both `signed` and `unsigned int`? Some status flags should be different when the instruction is specified with `S` suffix, right? Such as setting overflow (`V`) flag. I am wondering is there another version of ADD/SUB to handle one of the integer.

Comment: Some further search shows overflow is indicated by separated flags for sign and unsigned operands. `VF` is used for signed overflow, and `CF` is used to indicate unsigned overflow. So it makes sense that signed and unsigned ADD/SUB could share the same instruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twos complement means there is no difference between signed and unsigned addition.  The s bit determines whether any flags are modified or not IF modified, then carry is the unsigned overflow/borrow and v is the signed overflow/borrow.  This is all described in ARMs documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Because ARM uses two's complement representation, signed and unsigned addition (similarly subtraction) are the same thing. The only difference is [how you *interpret* the flags afterwards](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473h/CEGBHJCJ.html), if you set them with the `s` suffix.